# How to maximize button width in Android?

Tags: android

How to ensure that a button width is always maximized regardless a smartphone or tablet screen size? The aim is to always guarantee that `MaxWidth Button = MaxWidth Smartphone`.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="20"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/submit" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:text="@string/version"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650761/dimensions-of-usable-space-in-window-action-bar-and-margin-excluded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the layout_weight of your button to 1. It will then occupy all available space in the table row.

Answer (score -1):

Replace button like this;

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_span="20"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/submit" >
```